# AND linq query on 3 different Lists

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have to query a list with 3 different string inputs. The input strings are of the form `string1|string2|string3`. So i need to split them `split('|')` before.

Now I need to query a list (`Locations<Location>()`) by comparing the values from 3 different arrays(`country[]`, `state[]`, `city[]`) obtained from splitting the strings.

I have a linq query for each as follows

Example: To match country

```
IEumerable<Location> loc =  Locations.Where(lc=> Country.Any(entry => lc.CountryName.   StartsWith(entry,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

I need to skip checking for State if the State string input is empty. So my solution was to:

1. Query Country first. if the string is empty return the original input list.
2. Query for States on result obtained from above Step. if the string is empty return the original input list.
3. Query for City on result obtained from above Step. if the string is empty return the original input list.

Is there a way to combine all the 3 into one LINQ query considering above issue?. Hope I was clear.

Current code with expected output

```
 private IList<Location> FilterLocation(
     IList<Location> locations, LocationRequest Request)
 {
     locations = FindCountry(locations, Request.Countries);
     locations = FindStatenames(locations, Request.States);
     locations =FindCitynames(locations, Request.Cities);

     return locations;
 }

 private IList<Location> FindCountry(
     IList<Location> locations, string Countrynames)
 {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Countrynames))
     {        
         string[] Country= Countrynames.Split('|');
         IEnumerable<Study> result = locations.Where(lc=> Country.Any(entry => lc.CountryName.StartsWith(entry,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

         return result.ToList();
     }
     return locations;
 }

 private IList<Location> FindStatenames(
     IList<Location> locations, string Statenames)
 {             
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Statenames))
     {
         string[] States =Statenames.Split('|');
         IEnumerable<Study> result = locations.Where(lc=> States.Any(entry => lc.StateName.StartsWith(entry,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

         return result.ToList();                                                       
     }
     return locations;
 }

 private IList<Location> FindCitynames(
     IList<Location> locations, string Citynames)
 {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Citynames))
     {
         string[] Cities = Citynames.Split('|');
         IEnumerable<Study> result = locations.Where(lc=> Cities.Any(entry => lc.CityName.StartsWith(entry,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

         return result.ToList();
     }
     return locations;
 }
```

Sample Output

```
     First Sample
        Input
        Countrynames = "Country1|Country2|Country3"
        Statenames = "State1|State2|State3"
        Citynames = "City1|City2|City3"

        Output
        Match Location with Country2,State1,City3

     Second Sample
       Input
        Countrynames = null
        Statenames = "State1|State2|State3"
        Citynames = "City1|City2|City3"
       Output
        Match Location with Country2,State1,City3         
        Match Location with Country10,State1,City3
        Match Location with Country15,State1,City3
        Match Location with Country8,State1,City3
```

In other words 
 if Countrynames = null Do not include in the search.
 if Statenames = null Do not include in the search.
 if Citynames = null Do not include in the search.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not entirely clear, but it sounds like you want something like this:

```
IEumerable<Location> loc = Locations.Where(lc =>
    (CountryList == "" || Country.Any(entry => lc.CountryName.StartsWith(entry,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
 && (StateList == "" || State.Any(entry => lc.StateName.StartsWith(entry,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
 && (CityList == "" || City.Any(entry => lc.CityName.StartsWith(entry,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))));
```

Here's my rewrite of your function:

```
private IList<Location> FilterLocation( 
    IList<Location> locations, LocationRequest request) 
{
    string[] countryList, stateList, cityList;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Country))
        countryList = request.Country.Split("|");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.State))
        stateList = request.State.Split("|");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.City))
        cityList = request.City.Split("|");

    return locations.Where(lc =>
        (countryList == null || countryList.Any(entry => lc.CountryName.StartsWith(entry,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
     && (stateList == null || stateList.Any(entry => lc.StateName.StartsWith(entry,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
     && (cityList == null || cityList.Any(entry => lc.CityName.StartsWith(entry,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I believe if suppose County is empty then this will match an entry similar to Country="",State="someState",City="SomeCity" but not an entry like Country="SomeCountry",State="someState",City="SomeCity".

Comment: If the Country is Empty then I need to skip looking for it.

Comment: fireBand: I can't tell if you're saying that my answer is correct or incorrect. Please write more clearly.

Comment: Sorry, its not what I needed. If any string is empty like Country or State. I should not be looking for it.

Comment: fireBand: In your question, `Country` is an array of strings, not a string. Please give some examples with inputs and expected outputs so we know exactly what you're talking about.